# Svelte: check a checkbox without forcing it to be checked

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I have kind of an interesting problem with a Svelte app I'm building. In one of the forms I have a checkbox that I want to toggle on once a certain condition has been met, but I still want to allow the user to uncheck it manually.

```html
<script>
    let number = 0;
    $: checked = checked || number >= 2;
</script>

<input type="number" bind:value={number}>
<label><input type="checkbox" bind:checked={checked}> Checkbox</label>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/89c1b4907b1140d6a31249f2ac09201c?version=3.46.4)

So once the number value is at least 2 the checkbox gets checked, but at that point it's impossible to uncheck it. What I want is that the "default value" gets changed to "checked" so to speak, but still allow the user to override. I hope my explanation makes sense!

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, managed to find a solution myself:

```swift
<script>
    let number = 0;
    let checked = false;
    
    $: {
        checked = number >= 2;
    }
</script>

<input type="number" bind:value={number}>
<label><input type="checkbox" bind:checked={checked}> Checkbox</label>
```

This allows the checkbox to be checked/unchecked automatically based on the form values, but still allows the user to change the selection state manually.

Comment: Two things: 1. You don't need curly brackets in your reactive statement, and you don't need to declare nor initialize `checked`. `checked` will be implicitly declared, and initialized depending on the value of `number` (to `false` in your current case since `number` is initially set to `0`). 2. After the user sets the checkbox manually, changing `number` might override the user's choice. Perhaps you should include a mechanism where once the user manually (un)checks, that choice remains? Depending on your use case, obviously.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Good points, but yeah this is how I want it to work in the real app :)

Comment: Ah crap, it doesn't work in the real app since I have other fields in the form too. So when I change the contents of a textarea for example, the checkbox reverts to its default value. I do indeed need to keep track of manual override it seems, ugh.

Comment: Hmm, the contents of the textarea should not interfere with the checkbox unless you explicitly set it that way. Any way you can share that code?

Comment: It's hard to explain. Basically I have a Svelte store for the entire form, so when anything in that form is changed, the calculation that determines if the checkbox should be checked runs again (since that uses $form as its input). But I found a workaround.

Comment: This helped me solve a checkbox that checks all checkboxes problem in svelte, thank you! Nice tricky solution to use a defaulted to false yet reactive variable.